# Как убрать public из URL в проектах Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть проект **dev.ru.**

Я залил в папку **dev.ru/lara** проект с laravel. Но проблема в том, что сам laravel будет доступен, только если зайти в **dev.ru/lara/public.**

Как сделать так, чтобы он был доступен по ссылке **dev.ru/lara**?

Пробовал класть htaccess в папку **dev.ru/lara**, который перенаправляет в public, но когда переходишь на **dev.ru/lara** laravel пишет not found. И laravel думает, что сейчас путь /lara. А должен /.

И получается надо всем роутам делать префикс /lara, но тогда ссылки на стили получаются неправильными. Стили подключаю через `asset()`.

**Пример:** есть openserver в нем домен dev.ru, в нем разные проекты, в том числе laravel в папке lara, при такой структуре сайт будет доступен по адресу dev.ru/lara/public/
http://joxi.ru/52agj8XH4DPo9r

В общем можно ли установить Laravel в подпапку и при этом не было в ссылках public?

Comment: Вы меняли app.url на dev.ru/lara? Попробуйте в App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider в boot добавить    
```
$url = $this->app['url'];
    // Force the application URL
    $url->forceRootUrl(config('app.url'));
```

Comment: Это конечно моветон, но ты можешь сделать так - в папку `/lara` вынести все из /public, это будет публичная директория. А всю структуру лары положить во вложенную папку (например `/lara/application`). В index изменить путь к bootstrap файлу и в бутстрап файле переопределить ($app->bind()) публичную директорию

Comment: Пробовал делать `forceRootUrl`, но когда заходишь на **dev.ru/lara/home** перенаправляет на **dev.ru/lara/lara/login**.

Comment: Если писать `forceRootUrl` , то нужно переписывать функцию `route` иначе дублируется префикс.  Второй способ помог, но тогда будет доступ все файл(env и т.п). Все таки хотелось бы узнать как люди делают в реальных проектах, чтобы в дальнейшем избежать таких проблем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Скопировать .htaccess из public и создать файл index.php который будет подключать index.php из папки public, но теперь стилям нужно добавлять префикс public/.
2. переписать функцию `asset()`, чтобы она сама добавляла public/ файлам.

У меня еще возникли проблемы с [laravel-filemanager](https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/). Он подключает картинки через `url()` вместо `asset()`. И если заходить на **dev.ru/lara4/laravel-filemanager**, то превью картинок не загружалось, но сам filemanager работал. А если заходить на **dev.ru/lara4/public/laravel-filemanager**, то превью загружалось.

сделал define('PUBLIC_FIX',true); чтобы перенаправлять filemanager на public

**index.php:**

```
<?php
define('PUBLIC_FIX',true);

function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
    return app('url')->asset('public/'.trim($path,'/'), $secure);
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/public/index.php';
```

**admin.blade.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.file_manager_url = '{{defined("PUBLIC_FIX") ? url('/public') : url('/')}}'
</script>
```

В итоге можно заходить как на **dev.ru/lara** как и на **dev.ru/lara/public**.

Если заходить на **dev.ru/lara/public** то файл сверху подключаться не будет.

## 2 Способ избавиться от public

Чтобы окончательно избавиться от public лучше всего настроить apache.
В openserver можно настроить так:

```
Alias /lara/ "%sprogdir%/domains/dev.ru/lara/public/"
<Directory "%sprogdir%/domains/dev.ru/lara/public/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

public/.htaccess после RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteBase /lara
```

Answer (score 1):

В корневой директории создайте файл `.htaccess` и напишите в нем следующее.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Пробовал. Когда заходишь на **dev.ru/lara** пишет "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Comment: @Алексей а еще какие то манипуляции делали? сейчас у меня стоит голый ларавел, и после этих строк в `.htaccess` урл нормально работает без `public`

Comment: А вы в подпапку заливаете или в корень сайта?

Comment: @Алексей В корень сайта

Comment: В корне сайта у меня работает, речь идет о установке laravel в подпапку проекта

Comment: @Алексей в вопросе дайте подробное описание? что за проект и что делаете что не работает?

Comment: Добавил описание.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81518/discussion-between-raz-galstyan-and-).

Answer (score -1):

Переименуйте файл server.php В корневой директории Laravel в index.php и копируйте файл .htaccess из папки /public в корневую директорию с Laravel.