# Как перенаправить с / на папку

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

Добрый день на моем хостинге нет указание открытия опр. папки как это сделать через htaccess  в laravel

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

*Мне нужно перенаправить со

> /

на папку

> public

**как это сделать?**

Comment: RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L] - попробуй, но не понимаю почему не изменить конфиг сайтевелибл в apache/nginx

Comment: Уже миллион подобных вопросов и не меньше ответов на него существует... https://stackoverflow.com/a/53516975/12593651

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как убрать public из URL в проектах Laravel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/866742/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-public-%d0%b8%d0%b7-url-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте файл .htaccess в корневой папке фреймворка LARAVEL и поместите туда этот код:

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, вроде даже мне понятно, хотя с htaccess никогда не работал.

Comment: @Qwertiy, мысль-то не раскрыта. почему автор ответа предлагает править файл `.htaccess` вместо изложенной автором вопроса конфигурации http-сервера? что не так с изложенной конфигурацией? это только глобальные вопросы.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, очень похоже, что в вопросе та же конфигурация .htaccess, а значит код из ответа можно вписать в неё, не?